# Difficulty adding Google APIs to AVD Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have installed all of the System Images available in Android SDK Manager under both Android 6.0 (API 23) and Android 5.1.1 (API 22).

If I select Google APIs (either 22 or 23) from the Target dropdown

[image: Select target 22]

It tells me "No system images installed for this target":

[image: No system images available]

But if I select a straight Android target, images for Google APIs are available:

[image: Google APIs available]

The same thing happens for 22 and 23. What do I need to do to be able select Google APIs as a target?